# Can anyone help me to solve this question please?

Tags: python-3.x

The following code can lead to an infinite loop. Fix the code so that it can finish successfully for all numbers.

Note: Try running your function with the number 0 as the input, and see what you get!

```
   def is_power_of_two(n):
     # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
      while n % 2 == 0:
        n = n / 2
      # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
      if n == 1:
        return True
        return False


    print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
    print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
    print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
    print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 3):

0%2 == is true, and n = n/2 when n = 0, my solution is:

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
# Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  while n % 2 == 0:
    if n == 0 :
      break;      
    n = n / 2
# If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
  if n == 1:
    return True
  return False
```

Comment: Soooo... you're solving someone's homework assignment? Please don't answer broad questions like these - they're off-topic (they show no work, with just a problem statement).

Comment: @David Makogon on the contrary, I believe this question is not just for the OP, in fact other people will visit this question in the future.

Comment: @TheMaker - it's a debugging assignment (again, with no effort shown). This has been discussed fairly thoroughly on meta (such as [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)), in case you're interested in learning more, and understanding why this type of question is off-topic. Also, note that the question has already been closed, for the reasons I pointed out already (and in that link I just shared with you).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I agree, this particular question is not clear, but other questions of this type are clear enough, and they deserve answers.

Comment: I stumbled across this as well while searching for the logic behind the answer so I could better understand how to solve problems like this in the future. Could anyone explain what to look for which shows where the infinite loop occurs, and how this was found?

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
    if n == 0:  # Check special case
        return False
    else:
        while n % 2 == 0:
            n = n / 2
      # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
        if n == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Please edit your question to give the full code. Thanks!

Comment: edited the post.

Comment: @TheMaker - Please stop encouraging folks to provide detailed answers to a question that is off-topic (too broad, just showing a problem statement with no work and no specific question). This really looks like a classroom assignment. Totally ok to post classroom assignments, but some effort must be shown (including what they've tried, where they're stuck, etc).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Actually sometimes you must let bygones be bygones.

Comment: @TheMaker - I... don't know what you mean by that. But also, another insight on answers like this one: note that it has no description explaining what they changed, or why a particular change solved the problem. This is a good thing to bring to the answerer's attention, and suggest that they add an explanation.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yes, that is what I meant.... this particular question is bad, but any classroom assignment questions that are clear deserve an answer.

Comment: @TheMaker - so that last bit is not true. The question can be crystal clear. But if no effort is shown, and it's just a dump of the problem description, then it doesn't fit here. Per the guidelines. The site is not designed to be a "post assignment and have someone solve it" site.

Comment: @DavidMakogon By clear, I meant effort is shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
 # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
    while n % 2 == 0:
        if(n == 0)
            return False # Except 0
        n = n / 2
  # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
  if n == 1:
      return True
  return False # edit indent


print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True

print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

Comment: Please fomat your question better. Thanks!

Comment: Better yet: Please don't post an answer to such a broad question that appears to be a classroom assignment, showing no work. And instead, encourage the OP to enhance their question to show what they've tried, where they're stuck, output, errors, etc.